# Akka actors concurrency issue

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Suppose I have three Actors communicate with each other: ActorControl, ActorA, ActorB.

ActorA and ActorB communicate with ActorControl. The messages they receive are mostly different but they also have one same message X. When they get X they both need to perform function Y.

To avoid duplicate code I took out the function Y to package object called common.

In this case it could happen that both ActorA and ActorB calling common.Y at the exact same time.

My question is whether this way I sabotaging the actors concurrency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can share code across actors, but you cannot share data. If your functions are pure (stateless and without side effects), then there are no problems at all.

Here are some examples:

```
object Helper {

  // Safe
  def incrementPure( total: Int, i: Int ) = total + i

  //Unsafe
  private var total = 0
  def incrementStateful( i: Int ) = { total += i; total }

  //Unsafe
  def incrementSideEffect( i: Int ) = {
    val total = readCurrentTotal()
    val total2 = total + i
    saveCurrentTotal( total2 )
    total2
  }

}
```

In the last two functions, you should provide some sort of synchronization. However, this can potentially affect performances, if you rely on parallelism.

Comment: If they were not pure, was there a difference if I use two functions with the same code or if I use one 'shared' function?

Comment: @tzofia Yes, you can have issues if they are not pure, but there are several possible fix. If you provide more information, I (or someone else) may be able to provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you give an example for case that there will be a difference between using one function or two equals functions (when the function is not pure..)? I can't manage to understand why there will be different...

Comment: @tzofia here are some examples. Those are common concurrency/distributed computing/parallelism pitfalls.

Comment: First - you answered my question (sharing code across actors is ok) so thanks. Second - regarding my comments - I think I wasn't clear enough.. I do understand why un-pure functions might be unsafe (as you demonstrated above), but I still don't understand why there might be a difference between shared code to replica of the code in case the code is not pure - is it unsafe in both cases?? (this is actually my first comment/wonder in other words).

Comment: @tzofia In the second example, if you replicate the code, you will have two `total` variables which makes it safe (but might requires an aggregation somewhere. In the example you will need to sum the replicated totals such as to get the real total). The third case would unsafe in both cases (replicated or shared).